# Call asynchronous functions inside loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, asynchronous, highcharts

I have an object `charts`,

```
 var charts = {
        chart1 : function (){
            return {
                key1 : value1,
                key2: value2,
                key3, value3
            }
        },
        chart2 : function(){
            return {
                key1 : value1,
                key2: value2,
                key3, value3
            }
        },
        chart3 : function(){
            return {
                key1 : value1,
                key2: value2,
                key3, value3
            }
        } 
    }
```

A function `callback`

```
function callback(instance){
    .....
    .....
}
```

I can draw chart `chart1` like this,

```
var chart = new Highcharts.Chart(charts.chart1(),callback);
// callback is a function which gets called when drawing of chart is completed.
```

And all charts like this,

```
 for(chart in charts){
        if(charts.hasOwnProperty(chart)){
            new Highcharts.Chart(charts.chart(),callback);
        }
    }
```

But, drawing a lot of charts simultaneously hangs firefox.
So, I want to call charts one by one on callback of previous chart.
(When drawing of one is completed, draw the second one and so on...)

I can achieve this by creating an array having names of each chart. On `callback` function, I will increment the index and call the next chart.

Here's the question,

***How can I draw all charts without manually creating a list of chart names ?***

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create an iterable array of all the keys in your object and then cycle through them one by one as each chart is done being constructed:

```
function makeAllCharts() {
    // make list of charts
    var chartList = [], pos = 0;
    for (chart in charts) {
        chartList.push(chart);
    }

    function nextChart() {
        if (pos < chartList.length) {
            var key = chartList[pos++];
            new Highcharts.Chart(charts[key](), function() {
                callback();
                nextChart();
            });
        }
    } 
    nextChart();
}
```

Because you can't iterate a list of keys directly from the object one at a time without a `for (x in y)` loop, you do need to create the intermediate array that can be iterated by incrementing the index.

Comment: Yes, its pretty much what I was thinking. Though you removed the necessity to manually create a list (array). I thought this could be achieved without creating an array.

Comment: You have to create some other type of data structure that lets you get the next value in the data structure each time a chart completes.  An array is the simplest such data structure.  An object doesn't sequential access so you can't use the object directly.  It can only be iterated with `for (x in y)` and that won't work for this type of problem.  An array is the simplest way to go.

Comment: Also, is there any reason that your `charts` data structure has functions in it rather than just objects in it?  For that matter, why isn't it just an array of objects that you could iterate directly in the first place.

Comment: Chart functions uses global variables which I calculate by calling some apis. At the start, glboal variables are set to `null`. So, I thought of creating `functions` rather than simple `objects`

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for JSDeferred Libary - http://cho45.stfuawsc.com/jsdeferred/